# applying !important to all properties' values once

Tags: html, css

I am giving !important to all of the css propertis' values like this

```
.someclass{
  color: #f00 !important; 
  background-color: #ff0 !important; 
  margin: 0 !important; 
  padding: 0 !important; 
  width: 100% !important; 
  display: block !important;
}
```

Is there any method to apply only once !important that all values get `!important` of `.someclass`?

**Edit**

suppose main div is controlled with some scripts and then how could I give !important to all at once.

Answer (score 6):

No, but there is a better way. Make the selector more specific than the selector that you want to override. You can for example specify the element name in the selector to make it more specific:

```
div.someclass {
  color: #f00; 
  background-color: #ff0; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Not only is it simpler, it's also possible to further override this with an even more specific selector. Adding `!important` only works in one level.

The [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of a selector is basically calculated by the number of identifiers, the number of class names and the number of element names that it contains, in that order. For example a selector like `div.item .cost` with two class names and one element name is more specific than a selector like `div span.count` with one class name and two element names.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it. Write better selectors instead.

[image: NO!]

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER:  NO there is not (as far as i know);

LONG ANSWER:
the css has a very nice but sometimes annoying hierarchy system

first of all adding `!important` is not an adviced move it can do some harms to your page speed and may be some hard times in your next editting to find what cause something not work as it intended.
you can make something stronger priority by determining it with its ID or by making it a decendant like this:

```
.somediv > li > a {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}
```

and it will over ride this:

```
a.something {
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff0;
}
```

and this will over ride both:

```
a#something {
    color: #f00;
    background: #0f0;
}
```

and these will override all but the second is stronger by the way:

```
a.something {
    color: #0f0!important;
    background: #00f!important;
}
a#something {
    color: #0f0!important;
    background: #00f!important;
}
```